# libtinfo.so.5 error when starting up dolphindb(JIT)

Tags: dolphindb

libtinfo.so.5 error when starting up dolphindb(JIT)

When I start up dolphindb(JIT version), there is an error:

```
./dolphindb: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to start up dolphindb correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The libtinfo.so.5 is missed.
You can find the libtinfo.so.5 by the command “find / -name libtinfo.so.5”. Then copy it to your path “/dolphindb_path/server”.